# In Tensorflow2.0, how do I implement a trainable set of Sample Weights?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

In summary, my problem stems from have a set of sample_weights that are trained along with the other weights/variables while fitting my network. I can't seem to figure out a way to update the values of my weight vector during training.

So, to simplify some of the code (not full actual model, just a simpler version for simplicity sake):

```
def initialize_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=2))

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")

    return model
```

I pretrain this model on my data (X: (, 28, 28), Y: (,10)), then augment the dataset with new generated virtual samples. As this isn't important to the problem, I won't include that portion of the code. But, once I have my new augmented dataset (X': (, 28, 28), Y': (,10)), I want to continue the training, but with a sample_weight vector:

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform([len(X_s)], minval=0, maxval=1, dtype="float32"), trainable=True)
W = W / tf.math.reduce_sum(W) # to enforce sum(w_i) = 1
```

The training is handled like so:

```
classifier.fit(X', Y', batch_size=800, epochs=10, validation_split=0.2, sample_weight=W)
```

This does indeed weight each sample properly, but I want these weights to change over the course of training. I've tried researching this, but I can't seem to find a solution that worked.

Thank you very much in advance - I've been struggling with this for a while now. I have tried:

```
classifier.layers[-1].trainable_weights.extend([W])
```

As well as using `tf.GradientTape`, but nothing seems to work.